# How to combine this MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql

```
I have 2 tables like this:

table:prices
id, project_id, real_min_price, real_max_price
1 | 100100 | 500  | 2000 
2 | 100100 | 900  | 3000 
3 | 100100 | 2500 | 3200
4 | 100100 | 320  | 3900

table:gifts
id, project_id, min_price, max_price, gift
1 | 100100 | 0    | 1000 | 10
2 | 100100 | 1001 | 2000 | 20
3 | 100100 | 2001 | 3000 | 30
4 | 100100 | 3001 | 4000 | 40
5 | 100100 | 4001 | 5000 | 50
6 | 100100 | 5001 | 6000 | 60
```

$ID = 100100;

// find highest price

```
SELECT MAX(real_max_price) FROM `prices` WHERE project_id='$ID';

$MAX_PROJECT_PRICE = $dbo->getOne();
```

-- returns 3900

// find the limit row which between min-max columns of this value

```
SELECT gift FROM `gifts` WHERE project_id='$ID' 
AND max_price>='$MAX_PROJECT_PRICE' ORDER BY max_price ASC LIMIT 1;

$MAX_GIFT = $dbo->getOne();
```

-- founded 4th row of the gifts table and returns 40

// remove other gift rows higher then MAX_GIFT value

```
DELETE FROM `gifts` WHERE project_id='$ID' AND gift>'$MAX_GIFT';
```

-- deleted 5th and 6th rows.

in this scenario

it will find max price as "3900" so, 5th and 6th row of gifts table will be removed.

but this way is really bad, it should be done in one query but how?

Comment: @RaymondNijland That's not entirely true. You can delete rows based on a selects statements using it in the delete statement.

Comment: @canerkoroglu which is your mysql version ?

Comment: In general, unless there are legal or political reasons for doing so, you wouldn't normally DELETE data from a database.

Comment: Okay you can except delete query, at least maybe we can combine first 2 queries to find MAX_GIFT value. Mysql version is 5.6

Comment: i know @JorgeCampos   `DELETE * FROM table WHERE column = (SELECT .. WHERE ...)` is indeed valid SQL... Don't see why it's important to know the MySQL version number.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Because depending on the version you can use new features (such as row_number, etc) or workaround ones (@var)

Comment: ok but you don't need those features or user variables for this question @JorgeCampos

Comment: @Strawberry I somewhat agree with your statement. Although it really depends on the software requirements. Not all software needs to keep data forever or at least people think that it doesn't until they do ;)

Comment: @jorgecampos even so, I think that would be managed in the archiving system- however that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Okay you can except delete query, at least maybe we can combine first
>   2 queries to find MAX_GIFT value.

To combine the first two queries you can do.

**Query**

```
SELECT
    gift
FROM
    gifts
WHERE
    project_id = 100100 
    AND max_price >= (SELECT MAX(real_max_price)
                      FROM prices
                      WHERE project_id = 100100;)
ORDER BY
    max_price ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

And using all three queries into one.

**Query**

```
DELETE FROM
  gifts
WHERE
     project_id = 100100
  AND
     gift > (SELECT
               gift
             FROM
               gifts
             WHERE
                project_id = 100100 
              AND
                max_price >= (SELECT
                                MAX(real_max_price)
                              FROM
                                prices
                              WHERE   
                                 project_id = 100100;
                             )
              ORDER BY
                max_price ASC
              LIMIT 1
           )
```

Comment: @canerkoroglu  You will need indexes on `gifts.(project_id, gift)` and `gifts.(project_id, max_price)` and `prices.(project_id, real_max_price)` then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to run the delete command based on your queries conditions:

```
delete from gifts where gift in
(
  select gift from 
  (
  select gift, @row:=@row+1 as rw 
    from gifts, (select @row:=0) a
   where (select max(real_max_price) 
            from prices 
           where project_id=100100 limit 1) < max_price
     and project_id = 100100
    order by gift
  ) sub
  where rw>1
);
```

Sample data and test.

```
create table prices (
id integer,  
project_id integer, 
real_min_price integer, 
real_max_price integer
);

create table gifts (
id integer,  
project_id integer, 
min_price integer, 
max_price integer,
gift integer
);

insert into prices values
(1,100100,500,2000),
(2,100100,900,3000), 
(3,100100,2500,3200),
(4,100100,320,3900);

insert into gifts values
(1 , 100100 , 0    , 1000 , 10),
(2 , 100100 , 1001 , 2000 , 20),
(3 , 100100 , 2001 , 3000 , 30),
(4 , 100100 , 3001 , 4000 , 40),
(5 , 100100 , 4001 , 5000 , 50),
(6 , 100100 , 5001 , 6000 , 60);
```

Running the query I provided you will get on your gifts table.

```
1   100100  0       1000    10
2   100100  1001    2000    20
3   100100  2001    3000    30
4   100100  3001    4000    40
```